# PHPUnit - one coverage report from multiple project folders?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage, clover

I have a project that is structured like so:

```
project
├── app
│   ├── phpunit.xml
│   ├── src
│   └── tests
│       └── unit
└── modules
    ├── module1
    │   ├── phpunit.xml
    │   ├── src
    │   └── tests
    │       └── unit
    └── module2
        ├── phpunit.xml
        ├── src
        └── tests
            └── unit
```

All of the core interfaces/classes are in `app/src`, and all of the extensions/implementations are in `modules/**`. Thus, the `src` folders contain all the Controllers, Models, etc., and the adjacent `tests/unit` folder contains all of the unit tests for these objects.

I'm trying to generate one `coverage.xml` report (and more importantly an HTML report) that contains the coverage results from *all* of the tests across both `app/` and `modules/`. Can anyone suggest the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is it necessary that every folder needs his own unit config?

Comment: @ins0 - not exactly. I have it configured like that because then each folder is itself independently testable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create one `phpunit.xml` in your project root folder.

When running PHP Unit just point to your project root and PHPUnit will run over every test files he can find.

The same goes with the generated `coverage.xml` that now includes all results from every testfile.

If you like to seperate test runs then look at the PHPunit Option `testsuite`.

Example:

```
project
├── phpunit.xml
├── app (testsuite app)
└── modules
    ├── module1 (testsuite module2)
    └── module2 (testsuite module1)
```

Insert into your `phpunit.xml`

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="app">
    <directory>app</directory>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="module1">
    <directory>modules/module1</directory>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="module2">
    <directory>modules/module1</directory>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

And calling with

`phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml --testsuite module1`

Comment: Hello, nice solution. Can It be extended to original OP's purpose? - have each module independently testable / distributable?